# How to fake a context when there's no widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here's my situation.

Let us say I have a Widget `W1`, with context `C1`. I also have a generic class like so:

```
class Klass {
  static void doSomething(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, builder: (context) => W2());
  }
}
```

I am calling `doSomething` in `W1` as follows:

```
Klass.doSomething(C1);
```

Now, when I do a `Navigator.pop(context)` in `W2`, I am getting

> Tried calling: ancestorStateOfType(Instance of
>   'TypeMatcher')

Now, I know with `Builder()` we can fake a context, but when it is a non-widget, what are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Builder` doesn't make a "fake" context – it's the real deal.

Similarly, you *cannot* fake a `context`, not can you obtain one outside of the widget tree.

The definition of `BuildContext` is that it represents the location of a `Widget` in the widget tree. Therefore it doesn't make to fake it, as you'll end up faking the widget tree itself.

---

Instead, you should refactor your method such that it doesn't need a `BuildContext`.

For example instead of:

```
 void foo(BuildContext context) {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/foo');
 }
```

we can have:

```
 void foo(NavigatorState navigatorState) {
   navigatorState.pushNamed('/foo');
 }
```

Comment: alright! How can we get the current NavigatorState though? Does just calling NavigatorState() give the current state?

Comment: `Navigator.of(context)` returns a `NavigatorState`

Comment: Not directly related, but had this question, I am listening to `push().then((res) {});` and I am popping with a value `.pop(val)` but `res` is being `null` even before `.pop()` is executed, am I missing something very common or does it warrant a separate question?